# How to add an asp.net website into a github repository?

Tags: asp.net, git, visual-studio

I started a asp.net website project yesterday and I would like to add it on a git hub repository.

The problem is that it seems that when you create a new website on visual studio, the project solution and the website stay on a different folder.

**What I tried to do:**

- Create an empty solution and then add the website inside.

**The result:**

It works for github, but visual studio lists an error message about the solution that doesn't actually affect the website itself(I still can run it) and it also makes visual studio asks me to save the solution everytime I close the project and it bothers cause it doesn't seem like it should happen.

I don't know if the solution is required in a asp.net website project. But I also don't know how to do it without it.

**So,how do I create a github repository that contains a asp.net website that will work to the people who download it without any problems ?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want to start in the folder with the `SLN` file. Outside of Visual Studio, open up a command line (Powershell or whatever), navigate to that folder, and run command `git init`.  This will start git for your repo.

Next I'd go here https://www.gitignore.io/ and get the Visual Studio `.gitignore` file to put in that same folder.

To commit to your repo, run these commands from the same folder:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Write a comment here"
git pull
git push
```

You should be good-to-go.  I try not to use git from inside VS; it's been buggy for years.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension, it works perfectly on ASP.NET projects, MVC projects, API and .NET Core.

Once installed, its just clicks away for publishing, committing and syncing all your files. And all your files are published in your GitHub repositories. I am using it and never had a problem with it. There is an instruction details on the page which are self explanatory.

[GitHub Extension for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.github.com/)